Could not able to run tests in anchor. Main error is anchor test command is not finding .ts file
The Error, I am receiving in the terminal after running the command 'anchor test' is :
 TypeError: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /home/ahmed/development/your-x/tests/your-x.ts

My anchor.toml file is this :
  [toolchain]

[features]
seeds = false
skip-lint = false

[programs.localnet]
your_x = "Cq4cbKbWqogFGTkodhNa68vxTu2rM47GzXvwQaAnNHTE"

[programs.devnet]
your_x = "Cq4cbKbWqogFGTkodhNa68vxTu2rM47GzXvwQaAnNHTE"

[registry]
url = "https://api.apr.dev"

[provider]
cluster = "localnet"
wallet = "/home/ahmed/.config/solana/id.json"

[scripts]
test = "yarn run ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 tests/**/*.ts"

and package.json file is this :
{
    "scripts": {
        "lint:fix": "prettier */*.js \"*/**/*{.js,.ts}\" -w",
        "lint": "prettier */*.js \"*/**/*{.js,.ts}\" --check",
        "test": "anchor test"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@coral-xyz/anchor": "^0.30.1",
        "@project-serum/anchor": "^0.26.0",
        "@solana/spl-token": "^0.4.8",
        "@solana/web3.js": "^1.95.3",
        "ts-node": "^10.9.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/bn.js": "^5.1.0",
        "@types/chai": "^5.0.0",
        "@types/mocha": "^10.0.9",
        "chai": "^5.1.1",
        "mocha": "^9.0.3",
        "prettier": "^2.6.2",
        "ts-mocha": "^10.0.0",
        "typescript": "^4.3.5"
    }
}

My updated tsconfig.json file is :
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["mocha", "chai"],
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2015"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "include": ["tests/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}


does this answer from a similarly-ish question help -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/62099904/11090641

@Jimii , nope, they are doing for the nodejs backend project, I am doing for the anchor test/mytest.ts file. Though lemme show you the tsconfig.json file.
{
"compilerOptions": {
"types": ["mocha", "chai"],
"typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"],
"lib": ["es2015"],
"module": "commonjs",
"target": "es6",
"esModuleInterop": true
}
}

nice. could you edit your question to include this and also the full package.json file? Is it also possible to share the github repo link?

i edited, I am not sharing the repo as it contains private addresses
